# htmlentities is not working properly in propel symfony 1.2

Tags: php, oracle, symfony-1.2

problem

- its replacing single quotes with double quotes

  echo $movement_data

output string :

```
    '200407', '200396', '200397', '200398', '200399', '200400', '200401', '200402', '200403', '200404'
```

propel code:

```
         $c->add(VmemberDetailsPeer::PERSON_ID,array(htmlentities($movement_data, ENT_QUOTES)),Criteria::IN);
         echo $c->toString();
         $person = VmemberDetailsPeer::doSelect($c);
```

propel query

```
 Criteria: SQL (may not be complete): SELECT FROM vmember_details WHERE vmember_details.PERSON_ID IN (:p1) Params: vmember_details.PERSON_ID => ''200407', '200396', '200397', '200398', '200399', '200400', '200401', '200402', '200403', '200404''
```

output:

```
   array(0) { }
```

what i need

- i need to pass same comma seperated string in where clause.
- if i directly push movement_data comm seperated string in array($movement_data)
- it output with special characters like '\2222\', and so on... that i have htmlspecial characters in where clause.

Don"t Use Htmlentities Result propel query

```
         SELECT FROM vmember_details 
   WHERE vmember_details.PERSON_ID IN (:p1) 

   Params: vmember_details.PERSON_ID => '\'200407\', \'200396\', \'200397\', \'200398\', \'200399\', \'200400\', \'200401\', \'200402\', \'200403\', \'200404\''
```

solution i tried with explode make string to array:

```
 $x=explode(",",$movement_data);
```

output:

```
      Array
     (
      [0] => '200407'
      [1] => '200396'
      [2] => '200397'
      [3] => '200398'

     )


       $c->add(VmemberDetailsPeer::PERSON_ID,$x,Criteria::IN);
         echo $c->toString();
         $person = VmemberDetailsPeer::doSelect($c);
```

propel query output:

```
      SELECT FROM vmember_details WHERE vmember_details.PERSON_ID IN (:p1,:p2,:p3,:p4,:p5,:p6,:p7,:p8,:p9,:p10) Params: vmember_details.PERSON_ID => '\'200407\'', vmember_details.PERSON_ID => ' \'200396\'', vmember_details.PERSON_ID => ' \'200397\'', vmember_details.PERSON_ID => ' \'200398\'', vmember_details.PERSON_ID => ' \'200399\'', vmember_details.PERSON_ID => ' \'200400\'', vmember_details.PERSON_ID => ' \'200401\'', vmember_details.PERSON_ID => ' \'200402\'', vmember_details.PERSON_ID => ' \'200403\'', vmember_details.PERSON_ID => ' \'200404\''
```

- i need to pass same string where clause .

Comment: htmlentities is wrong for database context - why do you use it?

Comment: you could see '\'200407\' appears in query

Comment: first: what is the content in $movement_data array? there should only numeric strings or integers there. When you say '\'200407\'' appears in the query, I could bet the array contains a string like "'200407'" (read: doublequote, singlequote 200407 singlequote doublequote).
The database will then convert the singlequotes to slash-singlequote.

Comment: is_numeric(movemnet_data):bool(false)

Comment: ?? first: typo in the variable name, second: no dollar sign, third: $movement_data is an array - use var_dump()

Comment: het lars you could see that on converting string to array it still not working at ll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You extract your data from a string and the output is that array

```
$x=explode(",",$movement_data);

Array
(
    [0] => '200407'
    [1] => '200396'
    [2] => '200397'
    [3] => '200398'
)
```

Then you pass that array to a function that creates and SQL statement.

Ok, now please see the code sample below

```
$a1 = array(1,2,3);
$a2 = array('1','2','3');
$a3 = array("'1'","'2'","'3'");

print_r($a1);
print_r($a2);
print_r($a3);


Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
Array
(
    [0] => '1'
    [1] => '2'
    [2] => '3'
)
```

The first array $a1 contains integers, the second array contains strings with numbers, the third array contains strings with numbers *wrapped in single quotes*.

And exactly this is your problem!

**You MUST remove the single quotes from the numbers**, because the driver WILL specially handle them (substitute ' by \') which is what you observed:

```
SELECT FROM vmember_details 
WHERE vmember_details.PERSON_ID IN (:p1) 

Params: vmember_details.PERSON_ID => '\'200407\', \'200396\', \'200397\', \'200398\', \'200399\', \'200400\', \'200401\', \'200402\', \'200403\', \'200404\''
```

In fact something different has happened there. You passed a single string which contained single quotes to the statement. The driver examines the string, encounters single quotes and replaces them with slash-single quotes.